# Closing and releasing JMS resources

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

The question is simple: How do I properly close and release JMS resources in a Java SE application. I use IBM MQ v8.

My problem is that IBM MQ for JMS seems to start a thread named "JMSCCThreadPoolMaster" which doesn't die when there's no more JMS in the application. It lives on until the application itself dies. This is not what I want. I want to be able to close down that thread pool programmatically. My application only does 2 secs of JMS on startup and then goes on to to do other things for weeks or even months in a fairly resource constrained environment. It seems unreasonable that that I'm not able to tell JMS that I'm done with using it after the first 2 secs, so that resources are properly released.

Here's a little test to prove the point:

```
package org.test.jms.producer.simpleconsumer;

import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConstants;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;

public class MyTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyTest.class.getName());
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, InterruptedException {


        // Do some JMS stuff in a separate thread.
        Thread jmsThread = new Thread(new JmsRunnable());
        jmsThread.start();


        // Wait some time to allow any background thread to properly 
        // close down.
        Thread.sleep(60*1000);

        // Print the threads that exist at this point in time.
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[100];
        int noOfThreads = Thread.enumerate(threads);
        for (Thread t : threads) {
            if (t != null) {
                System.out.println("   Active thread : " + t.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    private static class JmsRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {            
            try {
                // just do a connect and then immediately disconnect.
                JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
                JmsConnectionFactory factory = ff.createConnectionFactory();
                Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

                props.put(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
                props.put(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "localhost");
                props.put(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "dev");
                props.put(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "mychannel");
                factory.setBatchProperties(props);
                Connection connection = factory.createConnection(); // ++
                connection.close();
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Thread is closing");
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Something bad happened", ex);
            }
         }       
    }
}
```

At the point where I list active threads there should no longer be any active JMS resources held onto by application. Yet there's this background thread.

The line marked with "++" is what triggers the creation of the background thread named "JMSCCThreadPoolMaster".

How to properly close down? A solution specific to IBM MQ is acceptable, i.e. it will be ok for me to cast to IBM MQ specific JMS class.

Comment: What happens if you call interrupt() on the offending (JMSCCThreadPoolMaster) thread following the call to connection.close()?

Comment: @upcrob. Dunno. Haven't tried. Will do. But seems kinda hack'ish to me to do so.

Comment: @upcrob. Tried it. Has no effect.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to close this thread - try opening a PMR with IBM and asking them.

Comment: @TimMcCormick. Sad. I've opened [a thread on the IBM forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=fa6e1e8b-e95f-4026-ad49-94c9ff571d89&ps=25).